# How to drop rows with too many NULL values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to do some preprocessing on my data and I want to drop the rows that are sparse (for some threshold value).

For example I have a dataframe table with 10 features, and I have a row with 8 null value, then I want to drop it.

I found some related topics but I cannot find any useful information for my purpose.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/3473778/count-number-of-nulls-in-a-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473778/count-number-of-nulls-in-a-row)

Examples like in the link above won't work for me, because I want to do this preprocessing automatically. I cannot write the column names and do something accordingly.

So is there anyway to do this delete operation without using the column names in Apache Spark with scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test date:

```
case class Document( a: String, b: String, c: String)
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(new Document(null, null, null), new Document("a", null, null), new Document("a", "b", null), new Document("a", "b", "c"), new Document(null, null, "c"))).df
```

**With UDF**

Remixing the answer by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856939/david-griffin) and my RDD version below, you can do it using a UDF that takes a row:

```
def nullFilter = udf((x:Row) => {Range(0, x.length).count(x.isNullAt(_)) < 2})
df.filter(nullFilter(struct(df.columns.map(df(_)) : _*))).show
```

**With RDD**

You could turn it into a rdd, loop of the columns in the Row and count how many are null.

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd.filter( x=> Range(0, x.length).count(x.isNullAt(_)) < 2 ), df.schema).show
```

Comment: I can do it without converting to RDD. Hold on.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised that no answers pointed out that Spark SQL comes with few standard functions that meet the requirement:

> For example I have a dataframe table with 10 features, and I have a row with 8 null value, then I want to drop it.

You could use one of the variants of [DataFrameNaFunctions.drop](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@drop(minNonNulls:Int,cols:Seq[String]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) method with `minNonNulls` set appropriately, say 2.

> **drop(minNonNulls: Int, cols: Seq[String]): DataFrame** Returns a new DataFrame that drops rows containing less than minNonNulls non-null and non-NaN values in the specified columns.

And to meet the variability in the column names as in the requirement:

> I cannot write the column names and do something accordingly.

You can simply use [Dataset.columns](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@columns:Array[String]):

> **columns: Array[String]** Returns all column names as an array.

---

Let say you've got the following dataset with 5 features (columns) and few rows almost all `null`s.

```
val ns: String = null
val features = Seq(("0","1","2",ns,ns), (ns, ns, ns, ns, ns), (ns, "1", ns, "2", ns)).toDF
scala> features.show
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  _1|  _2|  _3|  _4|  _5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   0|   1|   2|null|null|
|null|null|null|null|null|
|null|   1|null|   2|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+

// drop rows with more than (5 columns - 2) = 3 nulls
scala> features.na.drop(2, features.columns).show
+----+---+----+----+----+
|  _1| _2|  _3|  _4|  _5|
+----+---+----+----+----+
|   0|  1|   2|null|null|
|null|  1|null|   2|null|
+----+---+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

It's cleaner with a UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def countNulls = udf((v: Any) => if (v == null) 1; else 0;))
df.registerTempTable("foo")

sqlContext.sql(
  "select " + df.columns.mkString(", ") + ", " + df.columns.map(c => {
    "countNulls(" + c + ")"
  }).mkString(" + ") + "as nullCount from foo"
).filter($"nullCount" > 8).show
```

If making query strings makes you nervous, then you can try this:

```
var countCol: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = null
df.columns.foreach(c => {
  if (countCol == null) countCol = countNulls(col(c))
  else countCol = countCol + countNulls(col(c)) 
});

df.select(Seq(countCol as "nullCount") ++ df.columns.map(c => col(c)):_*)
  .filter($"nullCount" > 8)
```

Comment: I'm all for solutions that don't involve switching to a RDD, I'm not overly keen on string-based query building. Can it be done without that?

Comment: Totally agree with you. Trying that now. Worst case, I think I can make a UDF that takes an array of columns and spits out the count in one fell swoop. Give me a sec.

Comment: I think I may have a solution mixing both answers up. Hold on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative in Spark 2.0:

```
val df = Seq((null,"A"),(null,"B"),("1","C"))
         .toDF("foo","bar")
         .withColumn("foo", 'foo.cast("Int"))

df.show()

+----+---+
| foo|bar|
+----+---+
|null|  A|
|null|  B|
|   1|  C|
+----+---+

df.where('foo.isNull).groupBy('foo).count().show()

+----+-----+
| foo|count|
+----+-----+
|null|    2|
+----+-----+
```

Comment: Maybe I have the question wrong, but this does not appear to answer the question as it:
1) Only looks at a single field.
2) Requires the field to be specified.